# Many docker container on one host

Tags: apache, docker, containers

I didn't find something about running many different webapp-container on one host. So for example I have two containers. On  the first I run an apache with owncloud and on the second I run a wordpress blog. Both of them have to run on port 80. How could I handle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`-p`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/#/connect-using-network-port-mapping) flag to map ports:

```
docker run -p 8080:80 owncloud
docker run -p 8081:80 wordpress
```

And than access owncloud with `http://yourdomain.com:8080/` and wordpress with `http://yourdomain.com:8081/`

It is common to combine `docker` with a reverse proxy like `HAProxy`.
With a reverse proxy you can pass request to `owncloud.yourdomain.com` to your owncloud container and from `wordpress.yourdomain.com` to the wordpress container. (or `yourdomain.com/owncloud` and `yourdomain.com/wordpress`)

Comment: Now I use HAproxy. Its really cool and you have many possabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use different ports in the host (otherwise you will get an error starting the second container).
To avoid that, expose one of the 80 internal port to another port in the host.
For instance, when running 'docker run':

```
docker run -p 8081:80 name_of_your_image
```

This will export the port 80 of your server in the port 8081 in the host.

Answer (score 0):

if you want you can use `docker-gen`, it's a simple script where you can balance the docker with a simple environment variables (on container).
This is the documentation:

```
https://github.com/jwilder/docker-gen
```